# I'm getting an error that says my random_number variable doesn't exist. Any advice on what I should do to create it?

Tags: sas

I'm working on homework and I need to take random observations from a data set. I am trying to create the random data set based on my teacher's coding instructions but I keep getting an error saying my random_number variable does not exist. I have posted an image of my code. Do I need to create the variable or make a proc sort for it?
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5lSn.png)

Here are the error logs:

434  proc print data= random_sample (obs=100);
435      var id country year random_number pr cl;
ERROR: Variable RANDOM_NUMBER not found.
436  run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
real time           0.00 seconds
cpu time            0.00 seconds

Comment: Also to clarify, the date is from a freedom house data brought in from a folder. ID stands for the id number given to a country.

Comment: Why did you post a link to a photograph and label the link as "code"?  Why not just paste the actual text of the code into your question?

Comment: Please do not post images of code - post code directly in the questions, there is a button you can select at the top that will format it properly (or indent 4 spaces).

Comment: Separately - I do hope your teacher explains `proc surveyselect` at some point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to select a random sample then one way to do this is creating a new column with a random number between [0, 1], then sort, then select the first N rows.

```
data want;
  set have;
  random_number = rand(“uniform”);
run;
proc sort data=want;
  by random_number;
run;
proc print data=want(obs=100);
run;
```

In case you need something different, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your photograph of code the data step that looks like it is trying to create a list of random numbers will fail because it does not have an END for the DO loop. (unless you have it at the end of some line that is out of frame from the camera.)